# Ajax returned values do not update when field value changes

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have an ajax form element, *age*, that I'm passing to a query within an ajax callback. The callback generates some product information and returns it as a part of the form array.

The problem is this: if I update the age field, the callback is fired, the query is re-run, and the wrapper is refreshed, however it isn't updating the wrapper div with the new information, it's reloading the initial information.

The code lives here: http://pastebin.com/vUrCMX7c

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Do you see any errors in Firebug's console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check for any errors in Firebug's console.
2. In Firebug's net tab, what is the value coming back from the XHR callback?

If the value coming back from the XHR is the old value, then your problem is on the server side. If the value coming back from the XHR is the new one, then your problem is on the client side (like JQuery not being able to find it's target element). Hope that helps.

Comment: Net tab is useful - I wish I could debug my ajax-returned errors using krumo!